# Unable to re size fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to change the height of the fancybox after the content is loaded.I tried using $.fancybox.update() but it dint work.I used it in the page which is loaded to the fancybox.

here is my initialization code.Btw i'm using fancybox 2.0.4

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".modal").fancybox({

    maxWidth    :500,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    minWidth    :500,
    minHeight   : 200,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : true,
type                : 'iframe',
    padding:1,
     modal:true,
    helpers: { 
        title:null
    }        
});
```

});

Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Naatan for creating the [autoSize implementation](https://github.com/Naatan/fancyBox) for fancybox2 which works exactly as i wanted it to.